# What "saving taxes" means?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

> **Both were legally defined offers to save taxes and attract rich people and/or their wealth from abroad.**
>
> *Swiss Democracy by Linder Mueller*

I got some definition of "tax savings" from internet goes like this:

> Tax Savings means the decrease in Tax paid or payable to the relevant
> Tax Authority (or, without duplication, the increase in any Refund)
> attributable to a Tax Benefit.
>
> *from [lawinsinder.com](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/tax-savings#:%7E:text=Related%20Definitions&text=Tax%20Savings%20means%20the%20decrease,attributable%20to%20a%20Tax%20Benefit.)*

My question is does the meaning of "saving taxes" is same as "tax savings"?
Can please someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty much the meaning: These offers would attract rich people to Switzerland by decreasing the amount of tax that they would have to pay (or perhaps increase a refund of the tax, which has the same effect)